# Cant get number input from string

Tags: c++, string, input, codeblocks

Just trying to get numbers from a string , using code blocks. dont know if code blocks is at fault cause i heard there is an issue when using stoi function.

just trying to do the following :

string input;

```
cin>>input;// user defined such as input="he gave 6 apples " ( taking only one number no matter how big )



int a;
a=stoi(input);// will be 6
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you might not be able to use `cin` to get a whole line. The spaces are disturbing. You should use `getline()` instead.
Second, i prefer using `int atoi(const char *)`.
code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int myFunction(string s)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        if(s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9')
            break;
    return atoi(&(s[i]));
}
int main()
{
    string s;
    getline(cin, s);
    int numFromLine = myFunction(s);
    cout << numFromLine << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Prefer to use character literals instead of decimal ASCII code.  Example: '0' instead of 48.

Comment: Your use of `atoi` will only return one digit converted.  Try using `std::istringstream` and `std::getline`.

Comment: Also, pass `std::string` by reference.  The `string` is a large object and will take up a lot of space when a copy is made and passed to the function.  Prefer `const` reference if the string is not modified.

Comment: You may want to declare `inFromLine` as `const` since it is not changed.  {Sorry about these, I've been working with static analysis tools and MISRA too much.}

Comment: Prefer not to use `using namespace std`.  Either use separate `using` statements, such as `using std::cout` or prefix each item, such as `std::string`.

Comment: second atoi would return the whole number, not one digit - try it!
thats because be gets const char*